# Properly disposing textures from tiled maps or sprites

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocos2d-iphone

I am unsure about how to completely kill a node that uses graphics in cocos2d-iphone.

So what exactly do I mean? Well, for instance, I have a `CCTMXTiledMap`. It uses some textures, right? Well, I no longer need to use this tiled map, so I *kill it*, and I assume that such textures a killed as well, and memory is freed.

I am using `[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo];` to get info about the textures currently held in memory.

```
    CCTMXTiledMap *map = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"myMap.tmx"];
    [self addChild:map z:0];
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache]
                             dumpCachedTextureInfo]; // I get 32MB usage.
    [self removeChild:map cleanup:YES]; // I assume this will "kill" the map.
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache]
                             dumpCachedTextureInfo]; // I STILL get 32MB usage
```

As you can see, removing the map from child doesn't seem to truly kill the texture being used by it.

How exactly am I supposed to free memory then? I think that the same happens with `CCSprites` etc. Acoording to `CCTextureCache`, I just keep stacking memory until my app crashes.

**Note**: I know I could use something like `[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];` and clean everything up. But that doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CCTextureCache` will only remove textures for which there exist *NO* references. I have not used the `CTMXTileMap` class myself, but maybe there are objects in there that reference the texture. The same happens with `CCSpriteBatchNode`. You must first remove the `spriteFrames`, then `removeUnusedTextures` from the cache, at which point the memory is reclaimed. Suggest you use `removeUnusedTextures` after removing the map as child.

I dont see an explicit cleanup in `CTMXTileMap`, it is relying on `dealloc` to remove its objects that could reference the texture. Maybe (not certain about this), you should give a chance to the autorelease pool to release finally the map, before taking a measurement again.

Comment: What about a CCSprite then? How do you dispose of your CCSprites?

Comment: hmmm ... will read coco's code a bit before i answer that :) ... i am going under the assumption that when i remove a sprite from its parent, the cache's retain count drops, and removeUnusedTextures will snif it out and flush the texture to reclaim memory. Not 100% certain.

Comment: @Omega : thank god for small mercies, the assumption is correct. removeUnusedTextures removes plain vanilla sprites (whose parent is nil). I confirmed this by running a quick test.

Comment: Yeah, it seems it works. The same with TMXTiledMaps. So, I just have to make sure that they have no parent, and their textures will become unused for clearing later, right?

Comment: yep, as far as i can tell. I was being fooled by one of my own 'creatures', a GEStickySprite that artificially holds on to some sprites because i prefer the hit on memory than 'time' ... so if i know a sprite is coming back real-soon-now, i make it sticky, and then i can removeUnusetTextures without taking too much of a hit on runtime.